# Using Nativescript and Angular 2 how can I download a file and save to the device?

Tags: http, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

As in the title: Using Nativescript and Angular 2 how can I download a file and save to the device?

It seems there is a getFile function within http module however this doesn't seem available within Angular 2 (https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http)

`res.blob()` also doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

getFile should work as expected in {N} + ng2 application as shown [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ng-framework-modules-category/http)

Basic examples on **how to create, read , update and delete files and folders** in NativeScript + Angular-2 application

[file-system  in NativeScript + Angular-2](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ng-framework-modules-category/file-system)

Comment: Hi Nick . Some links are broken here. Can you please fix that ?

Comment: Links updated to the base folders of these examples (as the application structure has changed recently)